Appveyor variable substitution in environment variables
I'm trying to do this
environment:
  - PYTHON: $HOME/venv3.10/bin/python

or, preferrably
environment:
  - PATH: $HOME/venv3.10/bin/python:$PATH

But the shell interprets $HOME as a literal value and doesn't perform substitution. Is there any reasonable way to USE environment variables in environment variables?

Does this answer your question? How to replace environment variable value in yaml file to be parsed using python script

Almost. That's very helpful, but appveyor does yaml parsing in a black box somewhere, so I wouldn't be able to invoke a different parsing
